# Add labels to superfish sub-menu <ul>s

Tags: routes, navigation

Long story short, I'm building a Superfish menu structure that looks like the following:

[image: 1]:![ []https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXdaz.png[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kosD.png)

I'm using superfish & have everything in order except the labels on each of the sub-menus (GUIDES and BUSINESS STRATEGIES in the image)

How can one duplicate the parent link & add it to the sub-menu as a label above the links?

Ideally the strcture would look something like:

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
  <ul>
    <span class="label">Link 2</span>
    <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
    <ul>
      <span class="label">Link 4</span>
      <li><a href="">Link 5</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Link 6</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</ul>
```

Thanks All, I'm stuck on this one, open to any & all solutions.

Edit: I should have specified that the labels need to be added automatically. I don't want to make the client add a bunch of duplicate labels by hand if I don't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Special Menu Items module](https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items). What does it do?

*"Special menu items is a Drupal module that provides placeholder and separator menu items" ([1](https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items))*

A placeholder is defined as

*"A placeholder is a menu item which is not a link. It is useful with dynamic drop down menus where we want to have a parent menu item which is not linking to a page but just acting as a parent grouping some menu items below it." ([1](https://www.drupal.org/project/special_menu_items))*

Which matches your description of 'labels' in your question.

Comment: I should have specified that it needs to be automatic, adding the labels manually for every sub-menu is going to get pretty extensive.

Comment: Perhaps you can modify the Special menu items module to make it so that if client ticks a checkbox, automatically a label (aka special menu item) is created?

Comment: I'm sure it's possible, it's a bit over my head though.